# Google Model Attribute get by name

Tags: google-app-engine

Can I get a google model attribute by passing a string to some function?

To illustrate:
If I were to do `.properties().keys()`, it would return all the attributes as a list of strings.
If `'Person'` is a model and `'age'` is an attribute of person, I would like to do something like this:

```
Person.properties()['age'] = 25
```

where I set the person's age to 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Python's `setattr`:

```
setattr(a_person, 'age', 25)
```

Comment: I guess in his case he wants the setattr :)